# Openshift - InternalError while connecting to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, mongojs

I am trying to connect to mongodb using below code:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var ip_addr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var port    =  process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

console.log('ip_addr: ' + ip_addr + ' port ' + port);

var server = restify.createServer({name: 'myproject'});
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.CORS());

server.listen(port, ip_addr, function(){
              console.log(server.name + ' listening at url ' + server.url);
              });

var connectionString = '127.0.0.1:27017/myproject';

if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
    connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + '@' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}

console.log('~~ connectionString: '+connectionString);

var db = mongojs(connectionString, ['accounts']);
var accounts = db.collection('accounts');
console.log('~~ db: '+ db + ' accounts:' + accounts);

var ACNT_PATH = '/accounts';

// get all records
server.get({path: ACNT_PATH, version:'0.0.1'}, findAllAccounts);

// defining call backs
function findAllAccounts(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    console.log('~~ Before firing query to accounts');

    db.accounts.find(function(err, docs){

                      if(docs){
                     console.log('About to return docs');
                      res.send(200, docs);
                      return next();
                      }

                     console.log('about to return error');
                      return next(err);
                      });
}
```

It is working fine till this line: `console.log('~~ Before firing query to accounts');`. After which it shows this error in browser:

```
{"code":"InternalError","message":"Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'"}
```

Any ideas, what could be wrong over here?

Comment: instead of `res.send(200, docs);` try `console.log(docs)` and see if you get some data back. Also, capture `connect` and `error` events with db to see if the connection worked.

Comment: I think the problem is with db connection since it is printing this log - '~~ Before firing query to accounts' but none of these: 'About to return docs' or 'about to return error'.

Comment: I will check for connect and error events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding below line at top of app.js file:

```
Object.assign = require('object-assign')
```

Reference link: [Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign' #120](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/issues/120)